# How do we call a multi-valued operator $L$ with $∃c>0:∀y\in Y:∃x\in X:(x,y)\in L\text{ and }\left\|x\right\|_X\le c\left\|y\right\|_Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, multivalued-functions

Let $X,Y$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces and $L$ be a multi-valued linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ with $$\exists c>0:\forall y\in Y:\exists x\in X:(x,y)\in L\text{ and }\left\|x\right\|_X\le c\left\|y\right\|_Y\tag1.$$

> **Question 1:** I'm not familiar with the theory of multi-valued operators. Is there an established notion for a multi-valued operator $L$ satisfying $(1)$?

It seems to be some kind of "boundedness" of the inverse $L^{-1}$.

Comment: @postmortes Don't know what you mean. I consider a multi-valued linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ as a linear subspace of $X\times Y$. The range of $L$ is $\mathcal R(L):=\left\{y\in Y\mid\exists x\in X:(x,y)\in L\right\}$.

Comment: @postmortes Why do you think that? A linear subspace $A$ of $X\times Y$ is a *multi-valued operator* by the very definition of that term. It is only *single-valued* (and hence can be treated as a "usual" linear operator) if $\forall y\in Y:(0,y)\in A\Rightarrow y=0$.

Comment: Ok, finally found it:multi-valued operators are normally called set-valued maps.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol-string you provide says that $L$ is surjective and bounded, so calling it 'invertible' or 'open' are both possibilities (the hypotheses for the Open Mapping Theorem for linear operators are exactly that).  However, there's an issue around set-valued mapping in that determining the pull-back and how that should be handled is a little trickier.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/28d9/26269f12d8f5a4d1267e87aa11cc3a290255.pdf
discusses an inverse-mapping theorem for set-valued operators in Banach spaces and might be useful to you.